# curl get request argument list too long

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, unix, curl

I need to `GET` data from a service. I am passing a bunch of ids to it.

The ids are stored in a file separated by commas

Example: cat id_file

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,.....10000.
```

There are thousands of ids in the file.

In my shell script I use

```
id_list=$(cat id_file)

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -X GET "http://prk.xyx.com/tpt/abc/v2/dce_info?Id=$id_list&mpId=0" > op_data.json
```

The curl command fails with the error `"/usr/bin/curl: Argument list too long".`

Now in curl `POST` we can specify `@filename`. Can we do something for get request?

Answer (score 8):

You can opt to read all options and URLs from a "config file" instead of from the command line using [-K](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-K), which will take away the length limitations completely. You can then also make that "config file" read from stdin if you want, so when you write a script you don't actually need to create a temp file for this purpose.

See also the [config file](https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline-configfile.html) section in the free curl book.

## Example

Pass arguments to curl using -K using echo:

```
echo '-H "Authorization: Bearer $token"' | curl -K- "http://prk.xyx.com/tpt/abc/v2/dce_info?Id=$id_list&mpId=0"
```

or if you instead have the command line options stored in a file:

```
curl -K arguments "http://prk.xyx.com/tpt/abc/v2/dce_info?Id=$id_list&mpId=0"
```

Comment: It's always awesome when the author of the tool you're using responds to questions!

Comment: Would be great if you could supply a working example